# Error When using Phantom JS and Browserify

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, browserify

I'm building a **site scraper** as a chrome extension, so I'm using `Node.js`.

I am using [node-horseman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-horseman) package to get the data and I want to use [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to create a bundle, so I can use it in the client-side as a normal javascript, without the direct need of `Node.js`.

When I run the script via terminal(`$ node horsemanOriginalFile.js`), it works fine. The problem is, when I create my `bundle.js` with `browserify` and call the file in my `index.html`(inside extension), I get the error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: spawn is not a function at spawnPhantom (chrome-extension://minjemngfgengofcddnbgjgnpaddoimm/bundle.js:13030:19)

CODE:

**horsemanOriginalFile.js**

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman
  .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0')
  .open('https://somesite.com')
  .wait(7000)
  .html()
  .log()
  .close();
```

**browserifyFileToCreateBundle.js** (I run `$ node horsemanOriginalFile.js` to create the `bundle.js` file)

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify();
b.add('horsemanOriginalFile.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js');
b.bundle().pipe(writable);
```

Then I call the created `bundle.js` in the client(that's when I get the error):

**index,html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason the package is called **node**-horseman. It obviously runs (spawns) a PhantomJS process from node.js - something that Chrome extensions can't do.

If you want to distribute this extension you would need a server part of it, a webservice, which would run Horseman. If it's meant for personal usage, you can  just fire up a simple local server with, say Express.js instead and drvie Horseman from there.

Comment: For now, is just for personal use. Can you give me a example on how can I do this using Express.js then?